# Join table and get value from table if value in this table is exist on other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. I need to do this job because I am starting to open free service for my game. I hope people can help.

Table 1 "online"

```
      |ID |
       ---
      | 1 |
      | 2 |
      | 3 |
      | 12|
      | 55|
```

Table 2 "User"

```
UserID|       IP
------------------------
  1   | 123.123.123.123
  2   | 123.123.123.123
  3   | 123.123.123.123
  12   | 123.123.123.123
  55   | 22.12.122.22
```

First. I get the value(ID) from "online" table. To get ID.

I have ID of one user is online.

Next. I use the value(ID) that I gotten from "online" table to select IP Address from "User" table.

When I got the IP from single user online. I get UserID from "User" table which have same "IPAddress". It will show many users who have same IP address.

My question. How can I make a query(my bonus query) for only 3 ID online from "online" table if there are so many user have same IP and online.

MYSQL version don't support select top. So I could not do this job. Please help.

Thank you all!

```html
<?php

session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include ("config.php");
error_reporting(0);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "data";
$account_Name = $_SESSION['userlogin'];


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


// get id online

$id_online = $conn->query("select ID from online");

$online = "";
while($row = $id_online->fetch_assoc())
{
 // list account online
 
 $online = $row["ID"];
 echo "- ID  online: $online";
 echo "</br>";
 $id_basetab = $conn->query("select UserID, IP from User where UserID='$online'");
 $ip = "";
 //show same ip list
 while($list = $id_basetab->fetch_assoc())
 {
  $ip = $list["LastIP"];
  echo "<hr>- IP: $ip</br>";
  $queryIP = $conn->query("SELECT UserID, IP FROM User where IP=$ip");
  echo "<hr>";
  //echo " acc Clone: </br>";
  
  while($row1 = $queryIP->fetch_assoc())
  {
     //echo "id: " . $row1["AccountID"]. " - Name: " . $row1["name"]. " - IP: " . $row1["LastIP"]. "<br>";
  }
  
 
  
 }
 
 // join table
 echo "<hr>";
 $queryshow = $conn->query("select  UserID, IP from online FULL JOIN User ON UserID=ID where UserID=$online ");
  while($result = $queryshow->fetch_assoc())
  {
       // is my $queryshow correct? I want to get value ID is exist or not if exist UserID on User table.
       // How can I create a query for only 3 users online if they have multiple account online.
    //I will make my custom query here.
  
  }
}


?>
```

Comment: How would you choose which three IDs you want?

Comment: Seeing as you are using `mysqli`, why not improve your security by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you, I want to select top 3 id online, if there are so many UserID is online(the example: id 1, 2, 3, 12 have same IP). I will run query to make bonus for ID 1, 2, 3.
But my MYSQL version don't support select top.

Comment: @Script47 I just run it for my own. Users will not see it

Comment: But what do you mean by ***top 3 ID online***? What defines ***top***?

Comment: *I just run it for my own. Users will not see it* - ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Script47 Every person had created multiple accounts. And login multi account. Top is only 3 accounts online if they same IP. From User table there are so many UserID and some ID of them are online

Comment: why so many queries doing this simple task?  you can use limit

Comment: @jonny I don't know much PHP. So could you please help me make an answer. Thank you

Comment: How are you checking to see if someone is online?  Because you are in essence getting all id then with the first query.  Are you getting the id at login?  im not sure if selecting all ids is efficient maybe select the one you are looking for

Comment: the "top 3" is still a little unclear top 3 compared to what most recent activity, logout time,  or just the top 3 results period?

Comment: it's compared with IP address. IP is last login ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should get the data you need at one time.
Now you can restructure and echo the results in your html and php one time.
This will cut down on a lot of code.
I used inner join and got both table's data at once.
If you need a where clause just place it between the inner join and order by section of this code. The LIMIT 3 shows the top 3 results in the data set

```
SELECT User.UserID, User.IP, online.ID 
FROM User 
INNER JOIN online ON User.UserID = online.ID  
ORDER BY User.IP DESC limit 3
```